# How to use dbWriteTable(2) properly?

Tags: r

I have started to use these packages

```
            require(RPostgreSQL)
            require(sqldf)
            require(caroline)
```

in order to process data between PostgreSQL an R.

I created a schema public in my database with some tables (one is called "data") and attributes. I imported the table "data" back into R as the data frame "test".
After manipulating it a bit I tried to upload it back to PostgreSQL DB into the (empty) table "data". However, I always get a error which I cant find a solution for:

```
         dbWriteTable2(con, "data", test, fill.null = T, add.id=T, 
          row.names=FALSE, pg.update.seq=FALSE)

        [1] "loading draft table to database"
        [1] FALSE

       Warning message:
       In postgresqlWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...) :
       table data exists in database: aborting assignTable
```

I know that the table "data" exists. Therefore I use dbWriteTable2 function, which seems to be able to insert the data frame into the corresponding attributes within the table "data".

When droping table data from PostgreSQL DB and rerun I get:

```
          dbWriteTable2(con, "data", test, fill.null = T, add.id=T, 
          row.names=FALSE, pg.update.seq=FALSE)


      Error in `[.data.frame`(dbGetQuery(conn, paste("select          a.attname from pg_attribute a, pg_class c, pg_tables t, pg_namespace nsp",  :
```

undefined columns selected

Just to sum up, how can I upload a data frame into an (empty) existing table within a PostgreSQL DB.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dbWriteTable2(con, "data", test,...)`? I guess that you have to give the name of the table as a character vector.

Comment: THX. But I get the following with your suggestion Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "id" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: I mean, the columns are identical to those in the data base. There is no id column in line one because add.id=F. Changing it to TRUE makes little sense because there is no "id" column in the db. Or do I miss something? However, when adding "id" to db and add.id=T I'll get Error in nchar(c) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

Comment: It's difficult to say without looking at your data. Furthermore, I don't have much experience with neither the `caroline` package nor postgresql. Did you try to do the same through `dbWriteTable`?

Comment: dbWriteTable worx somehow strange. It creates a table "data" and inserts the data frame "test" dbWriteTable(con, "data", test). I would like to insert the data farme into an existing table without creating it before.

Comment: That's not strange. That's exactly what it is supposed to do. The second argument is the name of the table of the database and the third is the values (as a `data.frame`) you want to put in the db. If you want to append the values to an existing table, just give the name of an existing table and add the argument `append=TRUE`.

Comment: nicola. you are my hero for today :--) thx!!